# how use access method in string interpolation angular

Tags: angular, angular6

Suppose to have this model:

```
    export class Book{
    private name: string;

     constructor(name: string){
    this.name=name;
    }
getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
```

If in my page.html I do:

```
<p>{{ book.getName() }}</p>
```

I obtain that getName() is not a function.Anyone can help me?

Comment: just {{ getName() }} is enough.

Comment: That simply means that book is not actually an instance of Book. My guess is that you expect Angular's HttpCLient to magically create instances of your class. That won't happen. If you're not explicitly using `new Book(someName)` in your code, you wo't have any Book instance.

Comment: @JBNIzet  I take the object from @Input() book: Book in my .ts,  But if I use public instance it works if I use the private instance with the access method I obtain an error.

Comment: Well, what the parent component is passing as input isn't a Book.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
get getName():any{
    return this.name;
}
```

in your html

```
{{getName}}
```